# Facing issue play mp3 in browser when new order comming time in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Right now i need to play mp3 in browser without user intreaction.

Current code:

```
const audio = new Audio(newOrderRing);
audio.play().catch((error) =\> {
// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
console.error('Error playing audio:', error);
});
```

In safari browser facing issue autoplay permission.

Error:

NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.

NotAllowedError: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

In safari i need to manully add permisson to play mp3 in site.
URL: https://memrise.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015889117-How-can-I-allow-audio-to-auto-play-on-Safari-

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.